# Consolidate URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I have a website with the following URL structure:

/[country]/city/[cityname]/
/[country]/city/[cityname]/events/[eventname]/
/[country]/city/[cityname]/sights/[sightname]/
/[country]/city/[cityname]/travel/

now I would like to count every visit to `<cityname>/events/*` `<cityname>/sights/*` and `<cityname>/travel/` towards the visits to `*/<cityname>/` so that in my report in Google Analytics I only get something like this:

```
 1. /de/city/berlin/      1.145
 2. /de/city/hamburg/       874
 3. /fr/city/paris/         786
 4. /at/city/wien/          458
 5. /it/city/roma/          359
 6. /ch/city/berne/         348
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

On the 'All Pages' view, you use the search box to filter your results to only include URLs with '/city/' in the URL.

[image]

Comment: this still leaves me with the separation into 4 URLs per City